# Apache SCXML: add a custom action

Tags: java, scxml, apache-commons-scxml

I'm working with Apache Commons SCXML 0.9 and I can't find how to add a CustomAction. I've found examples using v2.0-SNAPSHOT (which by the way I don't know where to get it), but it seems that doesn't work on v0.9, so far I got something like this:

```
CustomAction customAction = new CustomAction("http://my.custom-actions.domain/CUSTOM", "my", MyCustomAction.class);
List<CustomAction> customActions = new ArrayList<CustomAction>();
customActions.add(customAction);
```

For v2.0-SNAPSHOT I could write:

```
SCXML scxml = SCXMLTestHelper.parse("path/to/my/sm.xml", customActions);
```

and after that, get a `SCXMLExecutor` and call the `SCXMLExecutor.go` method, but I can't find any option for v0.9, please I need your help here.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I got it, I've found [this post](http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/fs-m-apache-s-c-xml/) where there is a full example (in spanish) using SCXML v0.9.
Here is the code I've wrote to add a custom action `onExit`:

```
MyCustomAction mca = new MyCustomAction();//MyCustomAction extends org.apache.commons.scxml.model.Action
State state = (State) getEngine().getStateMachine().getTargets().get("yourstate");
OnExit oex = state.getOnExit();
oex.addAction(mca);
state.setOnExit(oex);
```

and if you want to register an `onEntry` action, is almost the same:

```
MyCustomAction mca = new MyCustomAction();//MyCustomAction extends org.apache.commons.scxml.model.Action
MyCustomAction2 mca2 = new MyCustomAction2();//MyCustomAction2 extends org.apache.commons.scxml.model.Action
State state = (State) getEngine().getStateMachine().getTargets().get("yourstate");
OnEntry oe = state.getOnEntry();
oe.addAction(mca);
oe.addAction(mca2);
state.setOnEntry(oe);
```